# PostgreSQL read performance is terrible

Tags: select, postgresql-performance, primary-key

**Table**
id, description

**situation**
Contains 5 records
id is PK

**request**
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1

**Execution**
743 ms

**Question**
Why in heavens name is this so slow. Same design, samen query on MySQL runs in 0.09s

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Same design, samen query on MySQL runs in 0.09s

Both postgres and MySQL should execute this query in less than 50 microseconds.

Even the MySQL timing is ridiculous: 0.09s is 2000x longer than it should. However MySQL client only displays time with 2 fractional digits, so it should display 0.00s or 0.01s. The fact both MySQL and postgres report suspicious high timings makes me think the server is not local and network lag is factored in the timing.

If you use EXPLAIN ANALYZE, it will tell you the correct execution time, without network lag.

Other culprits may be: you're connected over WiFi, or you put 5 megabytes of text in the description column and something is wrong with the network, high cpu/IO load, server is memory starved and swapping, storage problems, dying harddrive, network is blasted by someone using bittorrent or worse, etc. Could be anything, check system stats, load, RAM, swap, cpu, network latency and throughput, ping, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely apologize, ofcourse it's client interaction time.
I executed the Explain Analyze and found it to be executing in 0.006

I apologize again, I should have known this myself.
Thanks